# Avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT with rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, rx-android, okhttp

I see a issue when use Place API with rxjava.

When fetching data so fast, api return `"status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"`.
And I want repeat to get data with specific delay time to avoid it. How to do it with rxjava operator.

```
getCompositeDisposable().add(
    getDataManager().getAtmsByBankName(nameSearch, location, radius, apiKey)
    .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
    .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
    .subscribe(atmResponse -> {
        if (atmResponse.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
            if (atmResponse.getAtmList() != null) {
                atmListLiveData.setValue(atmResponse.getAtmList());
            }
        }
        Log.e("LOG", "inside onNext");
     }, throwable -> {
         getNavigator().handleError(throwable);
         Log.e("LOG", "inside onError");
     }));
```

This is log with okhttp3:

```
D/OkHttp: {
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
<-- END HTTP (166-byte body)
```

I use Retrofit for http.

```
public Observable<ATMResponse> getAtmsByBankName(String nameSearch, String location, String radius, String apiKey) {
    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    //return apiInterface.getAtms(nameSearch, location, radius, apiKey);
    return apiInterface.getAtms(nameSearch, location, radius, apiKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `retryWhen()` operator to resubscribe to your source when an error occurs. Since the response from your source is a normal item, you have to convert it to an error condition:

```
.doOnNext( atmResponse -> {if ( !atmResponse.getStatus().equals("OK") ) {
                             throw new IllegalStateException();
                          })
```

(then add any further tests to make sure you have the right type of error)
Once it becomes an error, you then use `retryWhen()` to retry:

```
.retryWhen( throwable -> throwable.flatMap( t -> Observable.timer( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ) )
```

`retryWhen()` will emit the throwable that it caught and determine its response based on the result. If a value is emitted, then it will resubscribe to the source; if `onComplete()` or `onError()` are emitted, the subscription will finish normally. Using `flatMap()` allows you to adjust your reaction based on the type of error.